# Why does class derived from dict not show contains keys

Tags: python, dictionary, derived-class

With this code:

```
    class MyDict(dict):
        def __setitem__(self, k, v):
            print 'assignment', k, v
            self.__dict__[k] = v

    nsg = MyDict()
    nsg["b"] = 123
    print "G is: ", nsg
```

It prints

```
assignment b 123
G is: {}
```

If I add

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.__dict__.__str__()
```

it works:

```
assignment b 123
G is:  {'b': 123}
```

Similarly if I print `G["b"]` I get a KeyError except if `__getitem__(self)` returns `self.__dict__[k]`.

Why are the parent class, `dict`, like `__str__` and `__getitem__`, not automatically found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `dict` object does not store keys and values in a `__dict__` attribute; how could it, as the `__dict__` attribute is itself a `dict` object!

Use the overridden `__setitem__` method to add to the dictionary; best practice is to use `super()` to look up the original method:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        print 'assignment', k, v
        super(MyDict, self).__setitem__(k, v)
```

You could also use the unbound `dict.__setitem__` method:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        print 'assignment', k, v
        dict.__setitem__(self, k, v)
```

except that would hardcode the method and not len subclasses of your custom `myDict` class inject another intermediary `__setitem__` method.

Comment: Works perfectly. So this means that `dict` has a `__dict__` (because no exception in thrown and `print self.__dict__` prints "{}"), but does not use it... weird! In any case with your technique the keys-value pairs are added to the dict itself (not `__dict__`) so no need to define all the other methods (`__str__`, `__getitem__` etc).

Comment: Your *subclass* has a `__dict__` because it's a custom class and it doesn't use `__slots__`.